# Row in alert box jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have html table i tried to get row data in alert but this show error 
when i do this through table row click this is done but i want to do on button click

code

```
    $(function () {
        debugger;
        $('#table').on('click', 'tr', function () {

            debugger;
            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
            }
            else {
                $('#table', 'tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
            }

            var row = $(this);
            debugger;
            var value1= row.find('td')[0].firstChild.data;
            var value2= row.find('td')[1].firstChild.data;
            var value3= row.find('td')[2].firstChild.data;

            var s = {};

            s.value1= value1;
            s.value2= value2;
            s.value3= value3;

            alert(JSON.stringify(s));

        });


        $('[ID*=btnadd]').on('click', function () {
            var Vechile_ID = '<%=Session["Vechilevalue"]%>';

            var value1= $(this).closest("tr").find('td')[0].html();
            var value2= $(this).closest("tr").find('td')[1].html();
            var value3= $(this).closest("tr").find('td')[2].html();

                s = {};             
                s.value1= value1;
                s.value2= value2;
                s.value3= value3;

                alert(JSON.stringify(s));


        });
    })
```

how i do this .. this show an error on this line

```
var value1= $(this).closest("tr").find('td')[0].html();
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined(…)

pop up table

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "M.aspx/master ",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    debugger;
                    var m = JSON.parse(result.d).response;
                    var master = $('#table').DataTable({
                        "dom": 'Blfrtip',
                        "columns": [

                            {
                                "title":" Type",
                                 "data":" Type"
                            }, {
                                "title": "value1",
                                "title": " value1",
                                 "visible":false
                            },
                            {
                                "title": "value2",
                                "data": "value2",
                                "visible":false
                            },
                            {
                                "title": " info",
                                "data": " value3",
                                "render":function(data,type,row)
                                {
                        return row.value1+ row.value2+ row.value3
                                }
                            }

                        ]

                    });
                    debugger;
                    for(var i=0;i<m.length;i++)
                    {
                        if (m[i] !== null)
                        {
                            master.row.add({
                                "Type": m[i][0],
                                "value1": m[i][1],
                                "value2": m[i][2],
                                "value3": m[i][3]
                            })

                        }

                    }
                    master.draw();

                },
                error: function (error) {
                    debugger;
                    var r = error.responseText;
                    alert(Error);
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

data in pop up like this

```
Type    info  
type_2  34 2 def
 type_3  234 52 tef
 type_4  344 26 dhf
```

Comment: Please share your HTML.

Comment: Button will be in all the rows of table?

Comment: @RahulPatel check update

Comment: no THERE IS just one button @RahulPatel

Comment: There is only button and it is outside of table? And on click of the button you want the first tr of table as selector?

Comment: `.find('td')[0].html();`  <--- DOM does not have `html()`.... Did you look at the errors in the Developer console??

Comment: there is only one button outside the table ..  i want when i select row and then click on button then want to alert that data which is select .. @RahulPatel

Comment: @greenuser please check my answer. The selector for selected row on button click should be $("#table tr.selected")

Comment: i tried ur answer and this show error .. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined(…)  @RahulPatel Patel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are adding class `selected` to the `tr` which has been selected you can use selector `$("#table tr.selected")` in button click.

**Please try with below js :**

```
$(function () {
    debugger;
    $('#table').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        debugger;
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            $('#table', 'tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });

    $('[ID*=btnadd]').on('click', function () {
        var Vechile_ID = '<%=Session["Vechilevalue"]%>';

        //Get info of selected tr of table
        $("#table tr.selected").find('td:eq(0)').html();
        $("#table tr.selected").find('td:eq(1)').html();
        $("#table tr.selected").find('td:eq(2)').html();

        s = {};             
        s.value1= value1;
        s.value2= value2;
        s.value3= value3;

        alert(JSON.stringify(s));
    });
});
```

Comment: this show error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined(…) @Rahul Patel

Comment: @greenuser can you please try with updated answer. I have replaced $("#table tr.selected").find('td')[0] with $("#table tr.selected").find('td:eq(0)')

Comment: please check update.. how i select individual value from pop up when i check console this show like this  34 2 def  where i want to select indivual value like this .. value 1 =34 , value 2 = 2, value 3=def

Comment: "34 2 def" will be in a single "td" or it will be three different tds?

Comment: it is different .. on pop up i combine this . now i want to get  individually on button click

Answer (score 0):

with the refrence of @Rahul Patel answer i update this line and then this working fine for me

```
var value1= $("#table tr.selected").find('td')[0].firstChild.data;
```